# How to get more informatin regarding a Synology S.M.A.R.T error

Tags: smart, synology, seagate

I have a 3TB Seagate Barracuda (ST3000DM001-9YN1) that is less than a year old, and my Synology DS1512+ is reporting it as "S.M.A.R.T. Status = Abnormal" and telling me to replace the drive.

While I appreciate that I am being warned about an impending drive failure, I need more information than that in order to file warranty claim against this hard drive.  Is there any way to get more information about the specific problem that Synology has detected?

Output of smartctl --all /dev/hdb is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zPw5kvnH

Comment: What does your SMART status monitoring tool (`smartctl` etc.) tell you?

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to the output of smartctl --all /dev/hdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drive overheated at some point in the past.

```
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   061   038   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 39 (0 4 43 37 0)
```

Unfortunately it's not possible to be 100% sure of the exact temperature that it reached, only that it was quite a bit beyond the vendor's defined threshold. Though it's most likely that the normalized values are simply 100 minus the raw value, making the threshold 55°C and the maximum temperature reached 62°C. (And the current temperature 39°C.)

You cannot "clear" this; it is permanent and will remain visible on the drive throughout the remainder of its life.

It also might *not* be covered under warranty, though you'll have to check with the manufacturer to be sure. If it was the only drive in the box that overheated, and it's also running at a much higher temperature than the other drives, then you might be able to make the case that something's wrong with the drive.

Answer (score 0):

You drive is having so many errors:

```
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   095   095   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       6616
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       5380
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   084   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       2656
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   084   054   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2656
```

Also you are using old firmware CC4B while there is already CC4H: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOmx_EUxRs0